# Better way to build has_one association or update if it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My discount class has a sales_period. I want to write a method which can build this association when it does not exist, or updates it when it does exist. Currently I am writing the following if condition.

```
class Discount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :sales_period

  def fetch_period
    end_date = ...
    if sales_period.nil?
      build_sales_period( end: end_date )
    else
      sales_period.end = end_date
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to do this, similar to `find_or_create`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not quite what you're looking for but you can shorten it slightly.

```
def fetch_period
  end_date = ...
  period = sales_period || build_sales_period
  period.end = end_date
end
```

Comment: thanks, it is marginally better and I think that's the best one can do.

Comment: Yeah, it depends what the fetch_period method actually does but I'd consider moving that one line of logic to it's own method if you're using it in multiple places

Answer (score 1):

`find_or_initialize` is similar to [first_or_initialize](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#first_or_initialize). Ex:

```
def fetch_period
  end_date = ...
  sales_period.find_or_initialize_by_end(end_date)
end
```

Also, I'd rename `end`, it's a ruby keyword. You'll probably get some weird bug when something tries to `eval` the code or some such, and it'll be super confusing.

Comment: it seems that when end_date changes, if sales_period already exists, instead it will create a new record and leave an orphaned sales_period. i.e. it does not update existing sales period end date

Comment: You're right, I mis-read what you're trying to do. I'd say something like Bradley's answer is correct.

Comment: Maybe `sales_period.find_or_create_by_discount_id(id).update_attributes(end: end_date)`

Comment: I think only pitfall of this is that it will not work on unsaved discounts / I can't build a period. I will stick with my original answer.